# boost::variant - why is "const char*" converted to "bool"?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I have declared a `boost::variant` which accepts three types: `string`, `bool` and `int`. The following code is showing that my variant accepts `const char*` and converts it to `bool`. Is it a normal behavior for `boost::variant` to accept and convert types not on its list?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/variant/variant.hpp"
#include "boost/variant/apply_visitor.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

typedef variant<string, bool, int> MyVariant;

class TestVariant
    : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    void operator()(string &v) const
    {
        cout << "type: string -> " << v << endl;
    }
    template<typename U>
    void operator()(U &v)const
    {
        cout << "type: other -> " << v << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    MyVariant s1 = "some string";
    apply_visitor(TestVariant(), s1);

    MyVariant s2 = string("some string");
    apply_visitor(TestVariant(), s2);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

> type: other -> 1
>   type: string -> some string

If I remove the bool type from MyVariant and change it to this:

```
typedef variant<string, int> MyVariant;
```

`const char*` is no more converted to `bool`. This time it's converted to `string` and this is the new output:

> type: string -> some string
>    type: string -> some string

This indicates that `variant` tries to convert other types first to `bool` and then to `string`. If the type conversion is something inevitable and should always happen, is there any way to give conversion to `string` a higher priority?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think this is anything particularly to do with `boost::variant`, it's about which constructor gets selected by overload resolution. The same thing happens with an overloaded function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(bool) {
    std::cout << "bool\n";
}

void foo(std::string) {
    std::cout << "string\n";
}

int main() {
    foo("hi");
}
```

output:

```
bool
```

I don't know of a way to change what constructors a Variant has [edit: as James says, you can write another class that uses the Variant in its implementation. Then you can provide a `const char*` constructor that does the right thing.]

Maybe you could change the types in the Variant. Another overloading example:

```
struct MyBool {
    bool val;
    explicit MyBool(bool val) : val(val) {}
};

void bar(MyBool) {
    std::cout << "bool\n";
}

void bar(const std::string &) {
    std::cout << "string\n";
}

int main() {
    bar("hi");
}
```

output:

```
string
```

Unfortunately now you have to write `bar(MyBool(true))` instead of `foo(true)`. Even worse in the case of your variant with `string/bool/int`, if you just change it to a variant of `string/MyBool/int` then `MyVariant(true)` would call the `int` constructor.

Comment: To complete your explication: there is an implicit conversion from any pointer type to `bool`, and built-in implicit conversions are always chosen in preference to user defined conversions.  (The conversion `char*` to `std::string` counts as user-defined.)  As for changing the constructors, you can wrap the class in another class, or derive from it.  Depending on context, one of these may or may not be appropriate; both have some drawbacks.

Comment: I think one solution is to remove `bool` from `MyVariant` and use 0 and 1 values instead.

Comment: @Meysam: yes. I thought about recommending that, but then I thought you probably wanted a `MyVariant` initialized with `0` to be different from a `MyVariant` initialized with `false`. If it's OK for them to be the same, just remove `bool`. If they have different meanings, it's not that simple.

Answer (score 13):

This has nothing to do with `boost::variant`, but with the order in which C++ selects the conversions to apply. Before trying to use user-defined conversions (remember that `std::string` is a user-defined class for this purpose), the compiler will try built-in conversions. There is no built-in conversion from `const char*` to `int`, but according to §4.12 in the standard:

> A prvalue of [...] pointer [...] type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool.

So the compiler happily converts your `const char*` to a `bool` and never gets to consider converting it to a `std::string`.

UPDATE: It looks like this clearly unwanted conversion is being fixed. You can find a technical explanation of the fix [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0608r3.html).

Comment: This just bit me today with a pair of overloaded methods, one which took a `bool`, the other a `const std::string&`.  Unfortunate!

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to use is a string literal (not const char * itself).

Then, you could try std::string_literals (s-suffix for std::string).

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/variant/variant.hpp"
#include "boost/variant/apply_visitor.hpp"

#include <string>
using namespace std::string_literals; // enables s-suffix for std::string literals

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

typedef variant<string, bool, int> MyVariant;

class TestVariant
    : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    void operator()(string &v) const
    {
        cout << "type: string -> " << v << endl;
    }
    template<typename U>
    void operator()(U &v)const
    {
        cout << "type: other -> " << v << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    MyVariant s1 = "some string"s; // use s-suffix ("some string"s is std::string, not const char *
    apply_visitor(TestVariant(), s1);

    MyVariant s2 = string("some string");
    apply_visitor(TestVariant(), s2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
type: string -> some string
type: string -> some string
```